# System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException Issue

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

> **dbo.Images - Table**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRI9Z.jpg

> Image.cs

```
 public class Image
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string ImagePath { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
        }
        public class ImageDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

> ImageController.cs

```
       [HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(string category) 
{
    var myList = db.Images.ToList();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
    {
        myList = db.Images.Where(s => s.Category == category).ToList();
    }

    return View(myList);
}
```

> Search.cshtml

```
    @model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Image>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}
  <button>@Html.ActionLink("Extras", "Search", new { category = "Extras" })</button>
<button>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Search", new { category = "Home" })</button>

<div style="width:800px; margin:200px auto;  text-align:center;">
    <ul class="images">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            var imagePath = @item.ImagePath;
            imagePath = "/Images/" + imagePath;
            <li class="image-item" style="background: url(@imagePath) no-repeat;"></li>
        }
    </ul>
```

In relation the code above the application currently displays all the images found in the `dbo.Images` onto the `search.cshtml` having two buttons in order to filter from the `Category` that holds `Extras` or `Home` in the `dbo.Images` table. Although the page should display the images according to what `Category` button was clicked I'm having an error as per below.

- Button Clicked - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYSxm.png

Any ideas how to fix it?
Appreciate you help and thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the selected category as a query string parameter to your controller then filter your list in there. Notice that the ActionLinks will target your `HttpGet`action method. Replace the values with the categorys that you have. Also, you don't need the `data` attributes with this approach.

```
      <button>@Html.ActionLink("Category1", "Search", new { category = "Category1" })</button>
      <button>@Html.ActionLink("Category2", "Search", new { category = "Category2" })</button>
      <button>@Html.ActionLink("Category3", "Search", new { category = "Category3" })</button>


     <ul class="images">
       @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
          var imagePath = @item.ImagePath;
          imagePath = "/Images/" + imagePath;
          <li class="image-item" style="background: url(@imagePath) no-repeat;"></li>
      }
     </ul>
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Search(string category) // <-- selected category
  {
    var myList = db.Images.ToList();
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category)){
          myList = db.Images.Where(s => s.Category == category).ToList();
    }

    return View(myList);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've implemented the code as stated but as soon as a button is pressed an error is displayed and the application crashes. Search.cshtml loaded- http://imgur.com/ToMK2vy Button Clicked - http://imgur.com/TYYTI6S Code - http://imgur.com/4jhPoRc

Comment: I believe all action link should be like this: @Html.ActionLink("Search", "Image",.....); this way all the buttons hit the same action in the controller.

Comment: switched the 'category' type from TEXT TO NAVCHAR(MAX) but now another issue showed up - https://i.imgur.com/tEEvLLt.jpg

Comment: If you're using a `Layout.cshtml` page and `_ViewStart.cshtml` you can remove `Viewbag.Title = "Search"`. As for your exception, it has nothing to do with your datatype. It's telling you that you are trying to read from something that has no values in it. Wrap your `foreach` in a ´if(Model != null){}´ and examine your controller that gets the values

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. In this approach the user can select a category from the drop down list and click on the search button.

**Controller**

```
    private ImageDBContext db = new ImageDBContext ();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var myList = db.Images.ToList();

        return View(myList);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string category)
    {
        var myList = db.Images.ToList();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(category) || category == "All")
            return PartialView("_SearchResult", myList);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
            myList = myList.Where(m => m.Category == category).ToList();

        return PartialView("_SearchResult", myList);
    }
```

**Partial View: _SearchResult**

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Image>

<ul class="images">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        var imagePath = @item.ImagePath;
        imagePath = "/Images/" + imagePath;
        <li class="image-item" data-filter="Fashion" data-filter-    type="@item.Category.ToLower()" style="background: url(@imagePath) no-repeat; height: 200px;">@item.Category</li>
    }
</ul>
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Image>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
{
    <select name="category">
        <option>All</option>
        <option>Home</option>
        <option>Extras</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

<div style="width: 800px; margin: 200px auto; text-align: center;">
    <div id="result">
        @Html.Partial("_SearchResult", Model)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but tried it out (http://imgur.com/tvXbIOB) and it appears that when click the search buttons nothing happens. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you add the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js from NuGet?

Comment: If you don't mind or is better to keep the browser history, then @brroshan answer is a good approach. My approach won't add a back stack to the browser.

Comment: jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js is set =/ .. trying to implement @brroshan code but the application is crashing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!